# How can I use a token in a mailto link?

Tags: 7, tokens

I installed the *Token* and the *Token filter* modules.

I use a *mailto* link in the body of a block.

```html
<a href="mailto:info@mydomain.com?subject=The subject I want&body=Can you send me my invitelink for [site:name] please?">info@mydomain.com</a>
```

The token isn't replaced by its value.

How can I use a token in that link?

Answer (score 0):

Mark the "Replace tokens" checkbox as checked for the "Text Format" which you have chosen while creating the block. Text Format configurations can be found with this path admin/config/content/formats

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
The block containing the mailto: link was Full HTML and the replace tokens where enabled. Clicking on it opens my mail program and shows me all I want except [site:name] is not replaced.